# What are the applications of stochastic differential equations to number theory?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, number-theory, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, stochastic-differential-equations

This semester i'm taking a course about stochastic differential equations. This made me wonder what applications does this topic have to areas like number theory and algebraic geometry, specially arithmetic geometry. Unfortunately i wasn't able to find anything online, all i found was about applications to usual differential equations to number theory in [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29942/what-connections-are-there-between-number-theory-and-partial-differential-equati)

Answer (score 0):

First, let me mention a nice established connection between probability and zeta function

- [random matrices and the Riemann zeta function](https://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/zeta/random.htm)
- ["Notes on L-functions and Random Matrix Theory](https://aimath.org/%7Ekaur/publications/58.pdf)

it says the the eigenvalues for certain random matrices behave like the zeroes of zeta function along the imaginary line.

So then one can further study this problem using Dyson-Brownian motion (which is an evolution on the space of matrices) eg. as done here

["Relaxation to equilibrium and the spacing distribution of zeros of the Riemann ζ function"](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1751-8113/40/22/009/pdf).

The DBM is described by an [SDE for its eigenvalues](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/18/254a-notes-3b-brownian-motion-and-dyson-brownian-motion/)

$$\lambda_i=d B_i+\sum_{1 \leq j \leq n: j \neq i} \frac{d t}{\lambda_i-\lambda_j}$$

where $$B_1, ..., B_n$$ are different and independent Wiener process|Wiener processes.  Start with a Hermitian matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1(0), \lambda_2(0), ..., \lambda_n(0)$, then let it perform Brownian motion in the space of Hermitian matrices. Its eigenvalues constitute a Dyson Brownian motion.